# Apache runs after reboot, but does not work

Tags: apache, configuration, bind, reboot

I am running an Apache on Ubuntu which works pretty fine. However, if I issue 'shutdown -r now' and wait until the server has been booted successfully, the website won't show up in the browser.
Then, if I issue: service apache2 start, it'll show:

```
[Thu Jun 14 11:08:38 2012] [error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *.443 -- ignoring!
[Thu Jun 14 11:08:38 2012] [warn] The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default2 at line 18 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier ScriptAlias.
[Thu Jun 14 11:08:38 2012] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default2 at line 34 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Thu Jun 14 11:08:38 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 * Starting web server apache2                                                      FAIL
```

However, when I issue service apache2 stop, it'll show:

```
[Thu Jun 14 11:09:34 2012] [error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *.443 -- ignoring!
[Thu Jun 14 11:09:34 2012] [warn] The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default2 at line 18 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier ScriptAlias.
[Thu Jun 14 11:09:34 2012] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default2 at line 34 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Thu Jun 14 11:09:34 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
 * Stopping web server apache2              OK
```

However, afterwards  netstat -tulpn| grep :80 still shows:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      23561/apache2
```

Anyways, when I just kill the process shown above, e.g., kill -9 23561, I can successfully startup apache2 with service apache2 start and see my website again in the browser. So, for me it looks like, there is another apache2 running that uses a completely different configuration. Btw, I already assured that I have only one apache2 installation.
Can you help me out with this? Many thanks in advance!!! :-)

Comment: If you would post your configuration file it would be helpful.

Warning about "*.443" is concerning. It might be that somewhere you got it into virtual host configuration and it messes apache's startup process.